# Knot Diagram of the Trefoil with $4$ Crossings

Tags: knot-theory

Let $D$ be a knot diagram with $4$ crossings. Suppose that $D$ represents the trefoil. Is it necessarily true that $D$ can be obtained from the standard diagram of the trefoil by applying the Reidermeister Move I once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following diagram is two moves away from a 3-crossing diagram of the trefoil.

[image: A 4-crossing trefoil knot]

---

I found this by enumerating 4-valent graphs that could be knots (with some simplifying assumptions, there are only a couple), then assigning crossings, excluding figure-eights.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! By the way, are $n$-valent graphs the tool for finding all possible knots with $n$ crossings?

Comment: No, it is always $4$-valent graphs with $n$ vertices; the vertices represent where the crossings happen.  Roughly speaking, enumerating graphs is how knots are tabulated.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer again!

Comment: This diagram of the trefoil often appears by mistake when authors misdraw the figure eight knot. See, for example, page 213 of Erica Flapan's book "When Topology Meets Chemistry" (Cambridge University Press, 2000). (Now she's editing AMS Notices -- a journal well known for its sloppy work in knot theory!) --Ken Perko

Comment: @user43408 I've heard someone call it a "figure-ain't." (And as an aside, I appreciate how you have long been the keeper of knot theoretical truth, Ken, but your comment about Erica strikes me as being somewhat mean-spirited.)